# Run Azure Function every 10 minutes starting at 1 second before each 00:x0

Tags: javascript, cron, azure-functions

An Azure Function must run every 10 minutes indefinitely starting at 00:59:59 (hour, minute, seconds). The cron schedule I am using is unsuccessful.

I am using a Javascript Azure Function based on a timer, e.g.,

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
```

I don't believe there is a setting within an Azure Function to set a start date/time. The cron scheduler seems like the only option.

According to the Azure Functions documentation:

> The schedule expression is a CRON expression that includes 6 fields:
>
> `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}`
>
> Note that many of the cron expressions you find online omit the {second} field, so if you copy from one of those you'll have to adjust for the extra field.

Examples provided by the documentation:

> To trigger once every 5 minutes: `0 */5 * * * *`
>
> To trigger at 9:30 AM every day: `0 30 9 * * *`

`59 */10 * * * *` results in these execution times:

- Result: 11:40:59 | Desired: 11:39:59
- Result: 11:30:59 | Desired: 11:29:59
- Result: 11:20:59 | Desired: 11:19:59
- Result: 11:10:59 | Desired: 11:09:59

`59 */10-1 * * * *` is not supported.

The reason the Azure Function needs to start its initial run at 00:59:59 is that the function compares event timestamps that occurred in the previous 10 minutes to a 10-minute UTC time interval. If any event timestamps to the minute level match a the UTC timestamp within the interval to the minute level (e.g., `2018-12-21Txx:3x:xx.xxxZ` of the event at `2018-12-21T00:35:18.894Z` matches any UTC timestamp of this pattern `2018-12-21Txx:3x:xx.xxxZ`), an action is performed.)

I am stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but what you want is `59 9,19,29,39,49,59 * * * *`.

Comment: I appreciate this help, MarkXA!